# how to move columns in one table to other table in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, business-intelligence, powerpivot, msbi

I want to move(denormalize)two tables into another tabe,how can I do it?

have two tables like:- 'sales by category','product by category',
I want to move these two tables into another table which is 'products'.

*i tried Related function with calucated column and it won't work bcoz those tables sharing one-one relationship*

plz solve my issue who are familiar with data modelling and dax in power bi

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the merge function in power query, follow the tutorial on the below link it'll explain it better, this will allow you to join the tables you need into query, in turn creating a table in Power BI

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-shape-and-combine-data#combine-queries